# is ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED a googleapiclient.errors.httpError?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client

I am using the googleapiclient(Python) APIs like images().get(), images().insert() etc to list images, create VM instances etc

There were several ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED errors from google cloud last month which caused the following exception in my code

```
Exception: {'errors': [{'code': 'ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED',     'message': "The zone 'projects/<project-name>/zones/us-central1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later."}]}
```

I want to handle this error in my code by sending a unique error code from my server to the client to retry this request after sometime since the error is transient.

I am not able to reproduce this error willfully for the same reason...that its transient

I checked the googleapi code on GitHub at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client
but couldn't find ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
I need to verify if its an exception of type "HttpError" or some other class and then can handle it in my code

I am already handling exception of type googleapiclient.errors.HttpError in my code by printing an error message and raising it as urllib.error.HTTPError (the server sends the code e.resp['status'] for this case to the client)

```
except HttpError as e:
    printf('Failed to create %s: %s\n', instanceName,   
            e._get_reason())
    raise HTTPError(
            None, int(e.resp['status']), e._get_reason(), "", None)
```